# When is the release of Aptana Studio 3.0.7 or how to fix this bug in 3.0.6?

Tags: aptana

I have downloaded recently Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.6.201110251455 and I have the following Aptana Studio 3 bug which prevents me to work with PHP (a project based on Symfony2).

> http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3617
>
> Error while indexing module: ClassCastException: Variable cannot be cast to Identifier

Could you please let me know when Aptana Studio 3.0.7 will be released or how to get this bug fixed into Aptana Studio 3.0.6 ?

3.0.7 is tagged as Due: 02/Nov/11 in JIRA but I can't find where I can download it.

Answer (score 0):

3.0.7 is feature complete, but due to scheduling issues, it will out next month. In the meantime, grab the beta from preview.appcelerator.com.